# How to use independently defined input functions in a shiny UI module?

Tags: r, shiny

### Objective

Define custom inputs based on existing shiny inputs and use them in shiny UI module.

### Example

#### Working code

I have the full code of this simple app without modules that works fine:

```
library(shiny)
library(micromodal)

text_input <- function(id, label, width = "1200px", ...){
  textInput(inputId = id,
            label = HTML("<h4>",label, "<span style='color:red'>*</span>", "</h4>"),
            width = width,
            ...)
}
    
components <- div(
  text_input("namee", label = "Name"),
  text_input("hobby", label = "Hobbies")
)

surveyAppF <- function(){
  ui <- fluidPage(
      use_micromodal(),
      
      actionButton('start',
                   label = "Start",
                   `data-micromodal-trigger` = "survey"),
      
      micromodal(
        id = "survey",
        title = "SURVEY",
        content = tagList(
          components
        ),
        footer = tagList(
          
          actionButton('submit',
                       label = "Submit",
                       `data-micromodal-close` = NA)
        )
      )
    )
  
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}

surveyAppF()
```

#### Module

Now I want to make this app modular. So, I use `NS()` function for IDs. I believe that I need to do that for the `components` too because it contains inputs. But the following does not produce the working app. The app launches without errors but the modal does not show up:

```
library(shiny)
library(micromodal)

text_input <- function(id, label, width = "1200px", ...){
  textInput(inputId = id,
            label = HTML("<h4>",label, "<span style='color:red'>*</span>", "</h4>"),
            width = width,
            ...)
}

surveyUI <- function(id) {
  
  components2 <- div(
    text_input(NS(id, "namee"), label = "Name"),
    text_input(NS(id, "hobby"), label = "Hobbies")
  )
  
  tagList(
    use_micromodal(),
    
    # Button to start the questionnaire ---------------------------------------
    actionButton(NS(id, 'start'),
                 label = "Start",
                 `data-micromodal-trigger` = "survey"),
    
    
    # First page: Demographics (triggered by start_intake button) -------------
    micromodal(
      id = NS(id, "survey"),
      title = "SURVEY",
      content = tagList(
        components2
      ),
      footer = tagList(
        
        actionButton(NS(id, 'submit'),
                     label = "Next",
                     `data-micromodal-close` = NA)
      )
    )
  )
}


surveyServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      
    }
  )
}


surveyApp <- function(){
  ui <- fluidPage(
    
    surveyUI("survey1")
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    surveyServer("survey1")
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}

surveyApp()
```

I recognize that `NS()` needs to be used inside `textInput()` instead of my function `text_input()`. But I am not sure how to define my function in a way to use `NS()`. Preferably, I want to define the `components` outside of the module UI as there are many in my actual use case. How do I use these independently defined inputs successfully inside a module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to connect the start button to the micromodal you need  the following in the survey UI,

```
 actionButton(NS(id, 'start'),
                 label = "Start",
                 `data-micromodal-trigger` = NS(id, "survey"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It wasn't complicated at all as I was thinking.